# I need a definitive authority as to whether or not "flambant neuf" is absolutely invariable

Tags: expressions, adjectifs, accord

Some say that "flambant neuf" is absolutely invariable; other say that "flambant" is invariable but "neuf" must agree in number and gender;  yet others say that "flambant" is an adjective and so is "neuf" and therefore both must agree in number with the noun the phrase modifies:

For example, is it correct to write "les tables étaient "flambantes neuves", or rather "flambant neuves" or rather "flambant neuf"?

Answer (score 5):

You have the gist of it, that is whether in the phrase *flambant neuf*, *flambant* is considered as a present participle (no agreement) or as an adjective (agreement).

***Le bon usage*** (Grevisse, 10th edition, 772,B):

> Dans les expressions familières *(tout) battant neuf, (tout flambant neuf)*, la forme en *-ant* reste le plus souvent invariable.

Grevisse gives numerous examples with no agreement on either word and the agreement on *neuf* only is more frequent than the agreement on one both words.

> Des habits flambants neufs (Alexandre Dumas, *Le Comte de Monte-Cristo*)
>
> Des soldats battants neufs (Maurice Barès, *Colette Baudoche*).

He only gives one example with the gender agreement :

> C'est parce que la Belle-France est flambante neuve (G. Chèrau *Champi-Tortu*)

and he adds that the gender agreement is rare.

**[The TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/flambant)** makes a note about the fact that *flambant* is now considered as invariable but *neuf* can agree it is considered an adjective or an adverb:

> Dupré 1972 indique l'invariabilité de flambant semble acquise dans cette expression. Mais on observera (...) l'indécision de l'usage sur l'accord de neuf, traité tantôt comme adjectif tantôt comme adverbe`
>
> - Deux grandes valises semblables, flambant neuves, en peau de porc (Butor, *Modif*.,1957, p. 11)
> - Librairie flambant neuf, tout ensemble radieuse et dégoûtante d'argent récent (Du Bos, Journal,1927, p. 190)

The [BDLQ](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4392) says that *flambant* does not agree but that *neuf* generally agrees. It's what is generally taught at school, [e.g.](http://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2016/02/29/2286295-vestiaires-buvette-flambants-neufs-a-la-noyere.html):

> L’ajectif **flambant** dans la locution **flambant neuf** est toujours invariable, mais neuf peut varier en genre et en nombre ou rester invariable : *une voiture flambant neuf ou une voiture flambant neuve*.

**Usage**, tends to reflect the agreement on  *neuf* and and not on *flambant*, although we can find recent examples such as:

> Vestiaires, buvette, flambants neufs à La Noyère ([29/02/2016](http://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2016/02/29/2286295-vestiaires-buvette-flambants-neufs-a-la-noyere.html))
>   Des locaux flambants neufs ([28/06/2017](http://www.lejsl.com/edition-de-chalon/2017/06/28/des-locaux-flambants-neufs-pour-le-siege-du-spip-de-saone-et-loire))

An ngram reflects what Grevisse says, i.e., that the agreement on gender is rare. *flambants neufs* is much more frequent than *flambantes neuves*:
[image]

The *Parlons Français* blog's [advice](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/au-feu-a109042974) is to say:

> Des gradins flambant neuf ou, plus couramment, flambant neufs (de préférence à flambants neufs).

It is quite a good blog but it not an authority.
The Académie française [does not](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue) (yet) have an entry about *flambant neuf*. I do not have a *Bescherelle* at hand but it would be worth looking into it.

Answer (score 3):

Writing about about some brand new cars, I would write

> des voitures flambant neuves

Larousse states that:
http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/flambant/33977/locution?q=flambant#172263

> Flambant neuf, entièrement neuf et brillant (expression le plus
>   souvent invariable)

But also that:
http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/flambant_flambante/33977/difficulte

> Flambant reste invariable dans l'expression flambant neuf : une voiture flambant neuve.

So, in the "flambant neuf" expression, the adjective "flambant" is always invariable. But for the adjective "neuf", both variable and invariable versions are valid.

Comment: Although your answer is correct you can find more authoritative  sources than Larousse. The [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/flambant) and the [BDLQ](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4392) for instance.